# IdentityServer userinfo endpoint not requested after silent renew

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, identityserver4, oidc-client-js

we currently facing the problem, that the silent renew is going to not working after about 30min. We were able to determine that the SubjectId is missing on IS4.

When looking into the network tab in chrome for the client requests, the following order is visible:

1. authentication request
2. silent renew request
3. user info request

[network requests](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L1Jtm.png)

Step three is missing before the next authentication request and due to that the SubjectId, I guess.

Our access-token lifetime is 1 h, identity-token lifetime is 5 min. For testing purpose we set the silent renew to trigger every 4 min. 
We are using the oidc-client-js@1.4.1 in combination with the redux-oidc lib.

Is there anything we forget in our configuration on client / server side?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can you post the code here please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was not located on client side. The cookie for the user was expiring on the back end side.
[link to github with solution by the creator](https://github.com/IdentityModel/oidc-client-js/issues/659)

Answer (score 0):

i think you have to listen to UserLoaded events thus you will load the new user after a silent refresh request

```
this._userManager.events.addUserLoaded(args => {
  this._userManager.getUser().then(user => {
    this._user = user;
  });
});
```

getUser will be called after every silent refresh call to get the new user